# Login to Salesforce using jsForce when running Jest test

Tags: jestjs, salesforce, jsforce

I'm trying to login using the jsForce package while running a node test. No matter what I do, it fails out with the error message of...

```
Error: INVALID_LOGIN: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
```

I do not have this problem when spinning up my whole project. It logs in fine. I've double and triple check that the login url is set correctly and that the username and password are correct from my env file. I cannot find any answers on this.

Has anyone figured out how to actually login using jsForce while running a jest test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI if you're trying to login with Jest, make sure your password does not contain a '$' character. Due to the way Jest cleanses env variables, it will remove that character. It took me ages to figure this out. Figure it might help someone save some time.

Answer (score 0):

What (if anything) is in the user's login history in setup? Maybe you need "security token" or add IP to trusted list. maybe the endpoint is wrong, login.salesforce.com, test.salesforce.com or maybe admin blocked logging in from generic ones and you're supposed to use mydomainname.my.salesforce.com.

Comment: Turns out Jest cleanses the '$' character from env variable strings. Couldn't find why in the documentation but that was the issue.

Comment: Lol, what a "feature" :D

Comment: Gotta love it right? haha only caused me to question everything in my life. When I figured out that was the issue I almost face palmed.